# Greece to Scotland, flight connects at Turkey, will I need Visa for Turkey?

Tags: transit-visas, short-connections, turkish-airlines, greek-citizens

I am a Greek national and I will be traveling from Greece to Scotland. I booked my tickets with Turkish airlines. Both flights (to Scotland and back from Scotland) connect at Ataturk Airport (IST) for a few hours.

Will I need a visa for Turkey? Or is a passport or European identity card enough?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### No

I have been through IST multiple times, they will check your passport at security however no Turkish visa is required.

From the [IST website](http://www.ataturkairport.com/en-EN/preflight/Pages/Transfer.aspx)

> Transfer Passengers:(International Transfer Passengers With An 
>   International Connection Flight) A boarding card is issued for the passenger (if not issued in the country of origin) at the transit desk of the relevant handling company on the Arrivals floor. The passenger does not go through passport control. Instead, he/she directly proceeds through the transit area into the International Departures area. Baggage will be automatically transferred to the connecting flight.

Answer (score 3):

Your Greek ID card (or passport) is enough - you could even pick up baggage at Istanbul if you needed to (which you don't), because the Greek ID card (or passport) is valid for entering Turkey without a visa